# In HTTP post request, How to pass JSON array having multiple Object in URL query

Tags: arrays, json, http, post, query-string

I need to post a JSON array having objects at backend in a URL query parameter.

Here is the sample array:

```json
[
    {
        "question": "What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?",
        "answer": "1"
    },
    {
        "question": "What is the name of your pet?",
        "answer": "1"
    },
    {
        "question": "Who is your favorite musican?",
        "answer": "1"
    }
]
```

It is working fine with body parameters, but I have to sent in a URL query. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? You need to be more specific. What does your code look like that is sending the HTTP request? What coding language are you using? HTTP library? What is stopping you from putting the JSON in the URL query instead of the post body? The URL would look something like `http://server/document?json=[{...},{...}]` (with proper character escaping, of course), depending on what the server's requirements are for the content of the URL

Comment: Yes, URL should look like this http://server/document?json=[{...},{...}]. I am testing service from postman and we need to use post query params only as our middleware is not supporting body params. I have tried with encoding array but it didn't worked.

Comment: You haven't actually shown what you tried, or what the receiving server is expecting, so noone can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL Encode the query parameter. Try this URL:

http://server/document?json=%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22question%22%3A%20%22What%20is%20the%20name%20of%20your%20favorite%20childhood%20friend%3F%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22answer%22%3A%20%221%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22question%22%3A%20%22What%20is%20the%20name%20of%20your%20pet%3F%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22answer%22%3A%20%221%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22question%22%3A%20%22Who%20is%20your%20favorite%20musican%3F%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22answer%22%3A%20%221%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D

I generated the encoded parameter using https://www.urlencoder.org/.